# Deleting the text in UITextFiled when long press on a button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need same like iPhone phone application dial pad delete or clear button functionality when long press. I've tried adding  long press gesture to the button and written this code, but it's deleting the text completely. How can i achieve clearing or deleting the text with animation effect.

```
if (longPressGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        // If delete button tag find then delete the number
        if ([self.phoneNumberString length]  > 0) {

            self.phoneNumberString = [self.phoneNumberString substringToIndex:[self.phoneNumberString length]-1];

            self.phoneNumberField.text  = self.phoneNumberString;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Chandra Sekhar Kunchala, you have to do some more work around over here. take again wrapped string into another string and compare it you may achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, this is animated, it just happens so fast that you can't see it. You need to wrap your delete in a timer to achieve a more realistic animated effect. Have it so that as long as the long press is still active, delete a character only every 1/2 second (or whatever interval works for you).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please share with me the code.

Comment: Yeah it's worked. Added timer in gesture state begin and invalidate in end state.